# Inserting date value from nodejs to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying inserting one date value from expressjs to mongodb. I am using mongodb native driver.

The issue is when I am using creating an object and inserting it using that variable , the date is inserted as string. Here is the sample-

```
var expenseTest = {date: new Date()};

database.collection('expensemaster').insert(expenseTest, function(err, r){
    console.log("query executed");
});
```

Here the the value in DB-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584f9b6e8c06a5717d10ee59"),
    "date" : "2016-12-13T06:55:24.698Z",
}
```

But when I am inserting the object directly in the insert query its date is returning as ISODate(date).

Here is the sample-

```
database.collection('expensemaster').insert({date: new Date()}, function(err, r) {
    console.log("query executed");
});
```

The value in db-

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584fba82566fc8787e75a7ed"),
    "date" : ISODate("2016-12-13T09:08:18.441Z")
}
```

My question is -  what if I have to use insertMany to insert array of object having date as one of the field.

How can I get date as ISODate(date) in the db.

Answer (score 8):

When you insert instead of calling

```
database.collection('expensemaster').insert({date: new Date()}, function(err, r) {
console.log("query executed");
});
```

use this :

```
database.collection('expensemaster').insert({date: new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()}, function(err, r) {

console.log("query executed");
});
```

This will create an iso date for you to insert. I use `Date.now()` but you can insert whatever date you want there. Below is the console log of what the `.toISOString` does

```js
console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
```

Comment: Thanks @Dennington-bear for your input but my ask was opposite. I want date in DB as ISODate(date). Issue here is if I have array of object for ex- [{date: new Date()}, { --  }, { -- }]  and I want to pass this array directly to the insertMany query then how can I get ISODate(date)

Comment: `new Date(Date.now()).toISOString()` this is still going as string

Comment: I believe this is incorrect and made the same mistake which caused errors in my existing database. Do **not** use ```new Date().toISOString()``` when inserting into MongoDB database (instead just use ```new Date()```) because MongDB does the conversion for you and using .toISOString will make .find() operators or $gte operators on the database fail

Answer (score 7):

Use `new Date()` when inserting into MongoDB database. Do **not** use `new Date().toISOString()` when inserting into MongoDB database because MongoDB already does the conversion for you and using `.toISOString()` will make `.find()` operators or `$gte` operators on the database fail

Comment: This is the correct answer. Be aware of the rules around [string parsing to dates though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript). Ideally your date string should be in a [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2):

To save as a Date in MongoDB I did this.

```
items = [{
    serverName: 'myServer',
    checkDate: '2016-12-13T06:55:24.698Z',
  }]

addMany(items) {

    // to tell mongodb to save as a date
    items.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.checkDate = new Date(obj.checkDate);
    });

    return this.dbClient
      .then(db => db
        .collection(this.collection)
        .insertMany(items));
  }
```